Clarification Needed on Class Diagram Relationships for Employee, OrderMission, and Department
I am working on a class diagram for my internship. I have encountered a situation that I haven't seen before, and I'm not entirely comfortable with the approach I've taken. Here are the relationships I need to model:

Employee and OrderMission:

An Employee can be responsible for multiple OrderMissions, but each OrderMission can have only one responsible Employee.
An Employee can participate in many OrderMissions as an accompanying person, and each OrderMission can have multiple accompanying Employees.


Employee and Department:

An Employee is assigned to one Department only, but each Department can have many Employees.
An Employee can be the chief of one Department only, and each Department can have only one chief.



I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly model these relationships in a class diagram.
this is what i tried.


Rather than naming the associations you should place property names to where they belong.

Thanks for your answer, in each class i named the properties. I named associations just for more clarity.

The multiplicities appear to have been typed into the property name fields. The clue is the plus signs that show visibility. The association names you have would be clearer on the ends opposite the subjects of sentences.

Properties with types that are not data types should be made into association-end properties.

As Jim said. I'd guess that Christophe will chip in with a good answer soon. For me it's just too late now...

I'll use Mission instead of MissionOrder or OrderMission.
First of all an employee CAN be responsible or CAN accompany a Mission. This means that not all employees are necessarily linked to a mission (think for example of new employees before they get a role in their first mission). Consequently, on the Mission end, the multiplicities should be 0..* (or shortcut *).
We understand that any Mission requires a responsible, so 1 is ok. But do every missions have accompanying persons ? Moreover, in the lifecycle of a mission, when a new mission is created, are the accompanying persons known from the start? If the answer to either of these questions is no, the multiplicity on the Employee end should be 0..*.
On the employee/department it's likewise. The 1 on the Department side of work is ok. But it is not clear feom yor narrative if a department must have at least one employee. Assuming that the chief is also working for the department 1..* is ok. If not sure (e.g. a department could be created and the chief os only assigned later) prefer 0..*.
The chef association is not ok: not all employees manage a department. So on the department end, it should be 0..1.
The + on the associations end are for public visibility. If you'd use it, better add the role name, i.e. the name you would give to the property of the class at the opposite end that would refer to the class at the end of the association. In other words, it's much less ambiguous to write department next to the + on the end of the chief association on the Department class, than having an attribute department:Department.

Thanks a lot, very helpful! I fixed the multiplicities in the associations. To be sure that I understood the last part about public visibility correctly, I removed the attribute department: Department in the Employee class and the attributes employees: List and chef: Employee in the Department class. And i replaced those with the following associations:
(Employee Class)  * employee ----- 1 department (Department Class) and
(Employee Class) 1 chief ----- 0..1 chiefOf (Department Class)

Also another questions is it common that 2 class can have more than 1 association?

«Assuming that the chief is also working for the department…»
Required constraint on association "chief": subsets work.

@YassineRiahi Yes, this is common. You have some good a good example here. I'll give you another: a Person can drive a Car at a given moment in time, but the same Person can also own a Car, and it's not necessarily the same car (e.g renting a car on a journey while owning a car that stayed at the airport). The only thing you need to be careful about is if the two associations are not the same (e.g. reverse relationship).

@user6580165 you nailed it ! Indeed, this is a beautiful way of addressing it and avoid inconsistencies if this is the intended semantic. Because I have also seen this kind of design where the chief of one department (for example IT department) was him/herself assigned to the enclosing department (for example directorate of administration), i.e. the chief did not work for the department he/she managed. This is a way to show the hierarchy where in a company everyone including management has alsways a boss to report to (except the ceo)

Semantics could be:

chief must work in this department (this limitation is expressed);
chief should not work in this department (this is another restriction);
chief can work in any department (no restrictions).
The choice of semantics is up to the author of the question.
“1)” can be expressed by one association, then employees should be divided into chiefs and others (by specialization or attribute).


Restriction required: no more than one chief per department.

Thanks a lot to everyone who answered (especially @Christophe). I was unsure where to turn for help, so I thought it might be time to try Stack Overflow. I'm glad I did!
